# Multiple independent sets of random numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I want to generate N independent sets of random numbers in C++.

I tried with the `std::random`, however I can do it only by declaring multiple default_random_engines. It works, but it does not suffice for my case because I do not know a priori the number of independent sets that I need.

It is important, because I need to know that each set of randomly generated numbers obeys the selected distribution, I cannot just use the same function for all of my numbers.

Comment: Could you just reseed a single generator with the current time in milliseconds for each new set?

Comment: If I pick to generate all of the sets of random numbers in advance it would work. However I generate the numbers on the fly. eg. 

set1: 1 2 3 4
set2:  2 3 4 5

and then go generate one more for the set1 to make it:
set1: 1 2 3 4 5

So I need to make sure that no matter when I pick to add a number in the set, it has to obey its distribution

Comment: Before generating a set, set the seed to the current time as well.  Then each round of generation is seeded uniquely.

Comment: What's the difference between using multiple pseudo-random generators (possibly seeded in the very same millisecond) and using a single pseudo-random generator? Multiple generators are not really independent, nor is any of them really random. Maybe you need *different* distributions for the sets?

Comment: Different bounds for all of them (upper and lower)

Comment: I cannot see your problem.  If you need some run time determined number of integers, what would you do?  Why won't the same solution, with `int` replaced with another type, work here?

Comment: Looks a lot line an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you don't need multiple random engines, what you need is multiple distributions.

something like

```
std::default_random_engine generator;

std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distributionA(0.0,1.0);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distributionB(-1.0,2.0);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distributionC(-7.0,0.5);
```

and later do sampling

```
double a = distributionA(generator);
double b = distributionB(generator);
double c = distributionC(generator);
```

Comment: Prefer `std::mt19937` to `std::default_random_engine`.